# Flutter Scrollable navigation drawer with one menu item aligned to the bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a navigation drawer with a bunch of items and I want the logout item aligned to the very bottom of the drawer.

```
return Drawer(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      DrawerAccountHeader(UserType.worker),
      DrawerNavigationItem(
        "Home", 
        Icons.home,
      ),
      new ListTile(
        title: new Text('Jobs', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),),
        dense: true,
      ),
      DrawerNavigationItem(
        "Nearby", 
        Icons.location_on, 
      ),
      DrawerNavigationItem(
        "Applied", 
        Icons.check_circle_outline, 
      ),
      DrawerNavigationItem(
        "Hired", 
        Icons.check_circle, 
      ),
      Expanded(child: Container()),
      Divider(),
      DrawerNavigationItem(
        "Logout",
        Icons.exit_to_app,               
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image: How it looks]

But on smaller screen I get overflow error because that topmost column height is bigger than screen height. So I tried changing the column to a ListBox and then I get an exception "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height", because I have the Expanded() in between the items to make that gap so that Login buttons sticks to the bottom of the list.

Is there any way to achieve below?

1. Have the login button (and possibly a group of buttons) stick to the bottom of the screen when there's vertical space.
2. Make the drawer item scrollable when there's not enough vertical space.
3. (nice to have) The scrollable, the entire drawer can be scrolled. I.e. on a small screen the user will need to scroll the drawer to get to the logout option.

Comment: What do you mean by s.height, is it screen height?

Comment: If you are using flex in positioning of the button, you could try using `justify-content` or `align-items` depending on your main axis

Comment: @evgenii That solution is for react native I think, my question is for flutter.

Comment: @evgenii The flutter flex layout, in this case Column, does not scroll, which is what my problem is. I tried scroll view such as ListView or SingleChildScrollView and get the exception "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
Drawer(
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraint) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Header"),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text("Home"),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Jobs',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                  dense: true,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                  title: Text("Nearby"),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
                  title: Text("Applied"),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                  title: Text("Hired"),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                const Divider(height: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                  title: Text("Logout"),
                  onTap: () {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: Crazy Lazy Cat, Thanks that's great, that works. The only thing I would've loved is to have the scroll applied to the entire list of menu items. I.e: on a small screen logout button will be below the screen and they'd have to scroll up to see the logout. This is more a want than a need, I'll hang around a bit to see other answers that achieves this, then mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Align` widget to position bottom

```
    Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, //you can set it as per your requirement
          child: Container(
              child: Image.asset(
            "assets/drawerCycleImage.png", //or Text widget or More Any 
          )),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
      title:Text('Title')),
      drawer:Drawer(
      child:Stack(
      children:[
        ListView(
        shrinkWrap:true,
        children: List.generate(25,(ind){
          //SizedBox is to remain space for logout button !
          return ind==25 ?
            SizedBox(height:60)
           : ListTile(title:Text('Item $ind'));
        })
        ),
        Align(
          alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            height:60,
            color:Colors.black,
            child: ListTile(
            leading:Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title:Text('Logout')
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]
      )
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment:Alignment.center,
          child: Text('Hello !')
      ),
    );
  }
```